# Separate form into two columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, view

I tried splitting this form into two columns from another ticket I found on here but it is not working correctly.  (technically four columns - column one left labels, column two left fields, column three right labels, column four right fields). Unfortunately, it is all messed up.  Here is my view:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("EditTechTicket", "Ticket", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="container">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <form class="form-large">

            <div class="left-col"> 

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OpenUserId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <span style="font-weight:normal;">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OpenUser.FullName)</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OpenDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <span style="font-weight:normal;">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OpenDate)</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CloseDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <span style="font-weight:normal;">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CloseDate)</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right-col">

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <span style="font-weight:normal;">@Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })</span>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TechnicianId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <span style="font-weight:normal;">@Html.DropDownList("TechnicianId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TicketStatusId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <span style="font-weight:normal;">@Html.DropDownList("TicketStatusId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })</span>
                        @*<span style="font-weight:normal;">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TicketStatus, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.StatusId)</span>*@
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

            <hr />

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

and here is the code I added to my bootstrap.css file:

```
.form-large {
    /*max-width: 884px;*/
    padding: 15px 15px 10px;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
.left-col {
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    width: 442px;
}
.right-col {
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    width: 442px;
}
```

Here is the rendered code:

```
<form action="/Ticket/EditTechTicket/f2780334-6f2b-4a68-8733-a8d7d6cd28cc" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="9yy11Toj0Cg4Tse3jDfhf6L8ETk651NHGW_t-u0wWIlsgmzBS6ay7sk0eJif1pmr0tFT5dYyXxvJwMRnIxiJ2ZmfrChgnXVZlJgZQR9-0GM1" />    <div class="container">
        <hr />

        <form class="form-large">

            <div class="left-col"> 

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="OpenUserId">Ticket Owner</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <span style="font-weight:normal;">Daniel Blois</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="OpenDate">Opened</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <span style="font-weight:normal;">5/26/2015</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="CloseDate">Closed</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <span style="font-weight:normal;">5/26/2015</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right-col">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="CategoryId">Category</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <span style="font-weight:normal;"><select class="form-control" id="CategoryId" name="CategoryId"><option value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">Microsoft Office</option>
</select></span>
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="CategoryId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="TechnicianId">Technician</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <span style="font-weight:normal;"><select class="form-control" id="TechnicianId" name="TechnicianId"><option value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">Daniel Blois</option>
<option value="999600fc-709e-4463-84ad-d26894babb54">Mike Smith</option>
</select></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="TicketStatusId">Status</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <span style="font-weight:normal;"><select class="form-control" id="TicketStatusId" name="TicketStatusId"><option value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">Active</option>
<option value="a297c792-1224-4605-8a72-48d218d569e6">Deffered</option>
<option value="553f4c93-4a72-44bd-a9ce-fab4f87d4e08">Closed</option>
</select></span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

            <hr />

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: post the rendered HTML instead of your razor code

Comment: @Shyju I posted the rendered HTML in my original Post

Answer (score 1):

I assumed like this way...<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/z1zLo0g9/3/)**</kbd>

**HTML Part:**

```
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" >
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
    <label for="exampleInputName">Ticket Owner</label></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
   <label for="exampleInputName2">Daniel Blois</label>
    </div></div> 
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Opened</label>
            </div>
               <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail2">5/26/2015</label>
      </div></div>
    </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" >
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
    <label for="exampleInputName2">Closed</label></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
   <label for="exampleInputName2">5/26/2015</label></div></div> 
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Category</label>
            </div>
               <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
   <select class="form-control" id="CategoryId" name="CategoryId"><option value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">Microsoft Office</option>
</select>
      </div></div>
     </div>

 <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" >
     <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Technician</label>
            </div>
               <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
   <select class="form-control" id="CategoryId" name="CategoryId"><option value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">Microsoft Office</option>
</select>
      </div></div>
     <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Status</label>
            </div>
               <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
   <select class="form-control" id="CategoryId" name="CategoryId"><option value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">Microsoft Office</option>
</select>
      </div></div>
    </div>
```

Add this **CSS**

```
.col-xs-12{margin-bottom: 5px;}
.col-md-12 {margin-bottom: 5px;}
```

Comment: When I go to the demo there that is all in one column.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Updated my solution..check this  http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/z1zLo0g9/2/embedded/result/

Comment: That looks good.  Thank you I will examine it so I can understand the HTML.

Comment: Do you know a way to space the rows out evenly? so it looks neater?

Comment: Where in my .css file do I put that? I tried at the bottom and nothing.  Also which css file do I put it in Site.css or bootstrap.css?

Comment: Like this? `<style type="text/css">
    .col-xs-12{margin-bottom: 5px;}
    .col-md-12 {margin-bottom: 5px;}
</style>`

Comment: Nothing changed on the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80186/discussion-between-sheshadri-and-djblois).